# how could I use the label to display message in Salesforce lightning

Tags: lightning-aura-components

As you can see, I'm showing the errors in Salesforce lightning using hard-coded. Could I fetch the error message from the custom label from the backend?

```
         if (password.length == 0) {
            component.set("v.errorMessage", "New password could not be blank");
            component.set("v.showError", true);
            return
        }
        if (confirmPassword.length == 0) {
            component.set("v.errorMessage", "Confirm password could not be blank");
            component.set("v.showError", true);
            return
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

The answer is **Yes**. You can refer to a label using following syntax:

```
$A.get("$Label.namespace.labelName")
```

Refer to the documentations for more details.

- [Using Custom Labels](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/labels_value_provider_platform.htm)
- [Getting Labels in JavaScript](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/labels_dynamic.htm)

So your code becomes something as below, where ERROR_MESSAGE is defined as a custom label with your error message.

```
component.set("v.errorMessage", $A.get("$Label.<namespace>.ERROR_MESSAGE"));
```